SQL Server to PowerBI - Upload Data in encrypted format
I am attempting to use encrypted columns in my SQL Server database as output for a PowerBI dataset.
I set up 'Always Encrypted' to encrypt the data in my SQL Server Database. I would like to load the encrypted column into PowerBI without decrypting the data.
I have managed to load the data, but the encrypted strings do not look the same in the PowerBI dataset as they do in SQL Server:

PowerBI:

I would like to present the output just as it looks in SQL Server. Is this easy to do? Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you

Does this answer your question? varbinary to string on SQL Server

Why do you want to show user some gibberish though

The request is for a dataset to be submitted periodically, not to present in a report. The Gibberish would only be used to match records between submissions.

Why would one use powerbi to submit data. The whole thing sounds fishy, but good luck with your endeavour :)

I figured out that you can change the datatype of the column from Binary to Text in PowerQuery.
Before:

After:

It is not the exact same string output observed in SQL Server, but at least it is not a bunch of question marks and complex symbols.
